# Kafka Streams subsession: Sessioning by a subset of data and aggregate back

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to session by `(a,b)` using windows from a stream whose original key is `a` but it will be sessioned by `(a,b)`, `b` being a result from the value.
I get it by doing something like:

```
val storeByAB = builder.
    stream("topicname").
    groupBy((k, v) => new ABKey(k.a, v.getB())).
    windowedBy(mySessionWindows).
    aggregate(... aggregate into a List[Session])
```

Aggregation generates an enriched list of sessions (sometimes a *natural* session may have to be broken into more than one).

From there, once I get the sessions by `(a,b)`, I want to re-unite all the sessions in a SessionStore so I can materialize it and query sessions by the original key, `a`, and get as a result a `Map[ABKey, List[Session]]`.

```
val storeByA = sessionStore.toStream.
    groupBy((k, v) => new AKey(k.key().a)).
    windowedBy(mySessionWindows).
    aggregate(... aggregate into a Map[AB -> List[Session]] )
```

1. I've run a few tests. The second `toStream` gets called (I tested with a `foreach` printer), but the second aggregate method never gets called. Why?
2. Is the second windowing really helping? DSL-built `ReadOnlySessionStore` generates `Windowed` keys, but do not allow to query by time, so retrieval would include fetching all records for a key, and iterate them to find the records that satisfy a time-bound query.
3. Also, regarding efficiency, there are two repartitions there `(a) -> (a,b)` and then `(a,b) -> (a)`. Sessioning by `a` alone would need no repartition - but I would have to make the `(a,b)` sessioning in my code... which I guess is doable, but I wanted to leverage KafkaStreams' own sessioning capabilities here. Is any better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you transform the KTable changelog stream into a KStream and apply a second session window? It seems you want to do a `val storeByA = sessionStore.groupBy(...).aggregate(...)` instead. (About the second repartitioning: this is actually required, because if you hash on `(a,b)` it's not guaranteed that all keys with the same `a`-value will end up on the same partition.)

Comment: Just to not lose the windowing part. If I just agg by A, I'll get all of the sessions for key A but I'd lose time info. I guess you can add (start, end) values on the aggregator somehow though.

Comment: Note, that the first aggregation will emit updates to sessions, and thus doing a second windowing step will not work as expected (disable caching to see this effect). And yes, you can easily add the window start/end time into the value.